# Why does Windows connect to 40.77.226.246 and 65.52.108.29?

Tags: networking, windows-10

My question is rather simple
Why the hell is my operating system connecting to those IP addresses?
i recently installed a firewall and this firewall tells me that

- System is trying to connect to 65.52.108.29
- Explorer.exe is trying to connect to 40.77.226.246

i suspect that this has something to do with Windows update or sending anonymous stats about my device, but im pretty sure that i used manual settings instead of express settings while installing Windows...

I have found some search results about 65.52.108.29
but no results about 40.77.226.246

Anyone noticed this? and or can explain what those are?

Comment: They are harmless and are completely normal

Comment: That is what i was expecting. but now is my question. WHY? why does it connect this way, i have disabled the feedback settings and any other options that i am aware of but still it tries to send data.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to find out:

```
> nslookup 65.52.108.29
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

Name:    msnbot-65-52-108-29.search.msn.com
Address:  65.52.108.29
```

which means it's probably related to <strike>the built-in search function in Windows</strike> telemetry.

```
> nslookup 40.77.226.246
Server:  resolver1.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

*** resolver1.opendns.com can't find 40.77.226.246: Non-existent domain
```

But if we search a little bit more, we can find that the second IP address is tied to `client.wns.windows.com`  ([source](http://40.77.226.246.ipaddress.com/)) which is the [Windows Push Notification Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Push_Notification_Service).

So, they're perfectly harmless.

Comment: i dont seem to understand how you linked 40.77.226.246 with clinet.wns.windows.com

Comment: @Hysterics see http://40.77.226.246.ipaddress.com/

Comment: im still unable to locate where you got the client.wns.windows.com from i have looked at that page and im unable to find anything related to client.wns.windows...

Comment: @Hysterics http://i.imgur.com/zQJVHJW.png

Comment: We appreciate your contributions, but it may be a good idea to edit your answer and tell us how you utilized IPaddress.com, rather than mysteriously saying *"if we search a little bit more"*.

Comment: Wanna see my view? 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/87a1597a73e94b21a20efe7a5bec7732.png

now i need a new explanation for this issue haha...

Comment: Hmm, the site might have a cache that is located in different regions, and they have not been synced yet.

Comment: Probably a bad method.  Whoever is in charge of 65.52.108.29 can likely be in charge of the Reverse DNS for that IP address, and could set that to any value such as something.msn.com.  Therefore, this is not a reliable indicator that the address is even legitimate (much less determining what it is for).  The facts that https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-65-52-0-0-1/pft?s=65.52.108.29 and https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-40-74-0-0-1/pft?s=40.77.226.246 both point to MSFT are far more reliable indicators that the connections are being made to IP addresses used by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows 10 Telemetry:

1. [65.52.108.29](http://65.52.108.29.ipaddress.com/)  - Microsoft bingbot in Boydton, Virginia, United States.
2. [40.77.226.246](http://40.77.226.246.ipaddress.com/) - Microsoft Azure Server in Ireland, which is more likely too telemetry.

Comment: Can you please reference your source?

Comment: i get the first one but the second one is still a mystery since its not very clear what it is for...